# RecyclerView OnScrollListener() Issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-appcompat, onscrolllistener

I have around 32 records in json, I am using RecyclerView to show them and I have implemented OnScrollListener(...)

Question

I started an Activity, I fetched all 32 records, now when I do scroll, why I am again getting same 32 records again and again, whenever I do scroll, here is my implementation of OnScrollListener()

```
public void initializeOnScrollForRecyclerView() {
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                int visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getChildCount();
                int totalItemCount = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getItemCount();
                int pastVisiblesItems = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (!isLoading) {
                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                        isLoading = true;
                        mPostPresenter.loadPosts(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What does mPostPresenter.loadPosts(false) do? does it load json again?

Comment: @RageshRamesh check now I posted more code

Comment: I have added an answer have a look and see if it solves your issue. if it doesnt let me know and i will investigate further.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Implementation seems to be correct but for one condition it fails, try when dy > 0 like this (Also put this in the OnCreate of the Activity) :

```
    private boolean loading = true;

 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }


        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
        {

            if (loading) {
                if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
                {
                    visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                    totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                    pastVisiblesItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                        loading = false;

                        Log.v("...", " Reached Last Item");
                        loadMoreVideos(searchVideos);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you :) your solution worked for me, but I did not understand what is dy and dx stands for ?

Comment: dx - The amount of horizontal scroll.
dy - The amount of vertical scroll.

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath -  Hi. I need the same thing for horizontal recycle view. Want to call web service on last item visible. But i am not able to do that. Can you guide me please.

Comment: Check my another answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to trigger something when last item is reached

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //When last item is reached
    if(position == yourList.size() - 1){
        loadMoreMessages();
    }
  }

public abstract void loadMoreMessages();
```

Comment: TOP solution, 3 lines of code instead of previous combinatoric solutions, Thanks Veeresh

Answer (score 1):

You are using this

```
 if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount)
```

Which means once you have viewed 22 records you are loading again. And while loading again you are getting same data and appending it to your list.

I can see that you are using RXjava. When you are subscribing in loadPost check what data your observable is emitting.  i think its emitting the same data again i.e your 32 records and those records are added again and this is an endless loop.

Comment: If you are not using pagenation you can just remove the onscroll listener block.  If you are using pagenation then your issue is with your   mApi.getPosts() block.  If your server has used pagenation then you will have to send a page number in your request.

Comment: remove onscroll Listener for now. Once pagination is implemented you can come back to this.