# SetOnScrollListener in RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

I used listview to show some data.I wrote setonScrollListener in my listview

```
mTransactions.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

   }

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

if (mTransactionAdapter.getCount() > firstVisibleItem) {
    if (mTransactionAdapter.getItem(firstVisibleItem) != null) {
        String date = DateUtils.formatToDayMonthInWordAndYear(mTransactionAdapter.getItem(firstVisibleItem).getDate());
        if (!date.equals(mTransactionHeaderWrapper.getTextView().getText().toString())) {
            mTransactionHeader.setText(date);

        }


    }
}
}
});
```

Now I'm using recyclerView and i don't know how i can use this code in RecyclerView.if onyone knows how i can rewrite my code please help me.thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000964/how-to-implement-setonscrolllistener-in-recyclerview

Comment: you can also refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35954531/6478047

Comment: maybe you are incorrect.I used custom headerListview with TextSwitcher @Redman