# RecyclerView Inside NestedScrollView Keep Scrolling after NotifyDataSetChanged - Issue

Tags: android

I added RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView. In First Attempt to get data from the server and render on UI, Also adding scroll listener after that. This is working fine for me.

Problem is when I scrolled to the bottom of NestedScrollView, another Server call to get more data, After adding data into a list, I called the notifydataSetchanged. But this time after refreshing the data NestedScrollView continue to scroll automatically.

Looks like :
1) The last scroll to bottom pauses first
2) refresh the list after the server API call
3) scroll that pauses, now resume automatically.

This is My Scroll Listener :

```
 nested_scroll_layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new 
   ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            View view = 
    nested_scroll_layout.getChildAt(nested_scroll_layout.getChildCount() - 1);

            int diff = (view.getBottom() - (nested_scroll_layout.getHeight() 
    + nested_scroll_layout
                    .getScrollY()));

            if (diff == 0 && !isCommentaryLoading) {
                isCommentaryLoading = true;
                hitCommentryApi(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

======================================

After API responded successfully, Add data into the current list.

```
then `commentaryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
```

Comment: you could add scroll listener in recyclerview rather than nested scroll view tree observer. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35954410/recyclerview-onscrolllistener-issue

Comment: But i need to do in NestedScrollView as there are some more views with recyclerview that need to scrolled.

Inside NestedScrollView , Scroll Listener on RecyclerView not Working, thats why implemented in Nested Scroll View